# 'printf': identifier not found

Tags: c++, printf, stdio

I have included stdio.h into my C++ project, why am I still getting this error? Also, after I added #include , printf(), in my code, was no longer underlined in red to suggest that there was any error.

Also, I would like to use the function, format(). Which library is that found in?

Comment: "Which library is that found in?" - Boost? TinyFormat? cppformat? You tell us.

Comment: *"I have included stdio.h into my C++ project, why am I still getting this error?"* - please provide your compile command, your link command, and the exact error you are receiving. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: *"I would like to use the function, format()..."* - that's *not* a standard C library function. What did you have in mind? Are you using an external library? Do you have a reference to the function?

Comment: As with spelling in word processors, IDE underlining is just a hint that there *could be* something wrong. Underlining doesn't definitely mean wrong, no underlining doesn't definitely mean correct.

Answer (score 12):

you must include stdio.h instead of cstdio.h

`#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 2):

Use
 **#include< cstdio>**
**using namespace std;**

after that you can use printf()

Comment: You should not motivate other people to do bad practices. [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)